# Initial setup for ssh on docker-compose

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I am using docker for MacOS / Win.

I connect to external servers via ssh from shell in docker container,

For now, I generate ssh-key in docker shell, and manually send sshkey to servers.

However in this method, everytime I re-build container, sshkey is deleted.

So I want to set initial sshkey when I build images.

I have 2 ideas

1. Mount .ssh folder from my macOS to docker folder and persist. 
   (Permission control might be difficult and complex....)
2. Write scripts that makes the ssh-keymake & sends this to servers in docker-compose.yml or Dockerfile.
   (Everytime I build , new key is send...??)

Which is the best practice? or do you have any idea to set ssh-key automatically??

Comment: i dont understand why do you want to use ssh this way, but you could build image with your ssh crap, and then use this image as base image in your Dockerfile of the apps... that way the keys stays there, so you will do `FROM whitebear/sshcrap:latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is typically to not make outbound ssh connections from containers.  If what you’re trying to add to your container is a binary or application code, manage your source control setup outside Docker and COPY the data into an image.  If it’s data your application needs to run, again fetch it externally and use `docker run -v` to inject it into the container.

As you say, managing this key material securely, and obeying ssh’s Unix permission requirements, is incredibly tricky.  If I really didn’t have a choice but to do this I’d write an ENTRYPOINT script that copied the private key from a bind-mounted volume to my container user’s `.ssh` directory.  But my first choice would be to redesign my application flow to not need this at all.

Comment: I am a Windows user. I used to use OSX before. OSX's shell is bash so you can use `less` `cat` and so on. However, On Windows Power Shell I need to learn the Power Shell command. So I try to use docker as daily works bash. But, it might not be good idea. I will install app like Cygwin or MingW

Answer (score 0):

After reading the "I'm a windows user .." comment I'm thinking you are solving the wrong problem. You are looking for an easy (sane) shell access to your servers. The are are two simpler solutions.
1.  Windows Linux subsystem -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux. (not my choice)

2. Cygwin -- http://www.cygwin.com -- for that comfy Linux feel to your cmd :-)

How I install it.

1. Download and install it (be careful to only pick the features beyond base that you need. (there is a LOT and most of it you will not need -- like the compilers and X). Make sure that SSH is selected. Don't worry you can rerun the setup as many times as you want (I do that occasionally to update what I use)
2. Start the bash shell (there will be a link after the installation) 
   a. run **'cygpath -wp $PATH'** 
   b. look at the results -- there will be a couple of folders in the begging of the path that will look like "C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin;..." simply all the paths that start with "C:\cygwin" provided you installed your Cygwin into "C:\Cygwin" directory.
   c.  Add these paths to your system path 
   d.  Start a new instance of CMD. run **'ls'** it should now work directly under windows shell.
3. Extra credit.

   a.  move the all the ".xxx" files that were created during the first launch of the shell in your C:\cygwin\home\<username> directory to you windows home directory (C:\Users\<username>).

   b.  exit any bash shells you have running

   c.  delete c:\cygwin\home directory

   d.  use windows mklink utility to create a link named home under cygwin pointing to C:\Users (Administrator shell) **'mklink /J C:\Cygwin\home C:\Users'**
   This will make your windows home directory the same as your cygwin home.

After that you follow the normal setup for ssh under Cygwin bash and you will be able to generate the keys and distribute them normally to servers.

NOTE: you will have to sever the propagation of credentials from windows to your <home>/.ssh folder (in the folder's security settings) leave just your user id. then set permissions on the folder and various key files underneath appropriately for SSH using **'chmod'**.

Enjoy -- some days I have to squint to remember I'm on a windows box ...